# Javascript error - Can't run .split on undefined

Tags: javascript, split

I imagine this is really simple but I just seem unable to achieve it.  I have this snippet...

```
var choice = location.href.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
```

It works fine until 'choice' is empty, then it throws the following error....

```
TypeError: location.href.split(...)[1] is undefined
```

I understand this is because you cant call split on a variable that is undefined, my solution i think is to store the variable and then split it if full or ignore it if undefined.

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: What do you get if you output just `location.href`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not super cool to do it like this, but if you expect *only one* parameter in query string you can do it like this:

```
var choice = (location.href.split("?")[1] || '').split("=")[1];
```

You will get `choice` as `undedfined` if it's not set in query string.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough info, but either the attribute href, of the 1 index of the first split is undefined, or the second item of the last split is undefined.

You would separate the split out into several statements.

```
var choice;
var firstSplit = location.href;

if (firstSplit) {
    var secondSplit = firstSplit.split("?");
}
if (secondSplit[1]) {
    choice = secondSplit[1].split("=");
}
```

Then you could use whatever returned from the last split.

Answer (score 0):

You would see this exception if you are attempting to split apart a URL that may or may not have a querystring. You should check that the querystring exists before attempting to manipulate it:

```
var choice;
var outerSplit = window.location.href.split('?');
var innerSplit;
if (outerSplit.length > 1) {
    innerSplit = outerSplit.split('=');
    if (innerSplit.length > 1) {
        choice = innerSplit[1];
    }
}
```

If you find yourself performing this type of querystring manipulation often, you might want to invest in a reusable function like the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).